# Inline assembly error: unknown register name ‘%%ebx’ in ‘asm’

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I am trying to create read() wrapper but getting this error:

> error: unknown register name ‘%%ebx’ in ‘asm’ in line 23 //(the bold line)

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
typedef unsigned int size_t;
typedef signed ssize_t;

extern int errno;

int main(void) {
    int fd = 0;
    char buf[128];
    size_t count = 128;
    my_read(fd, buf, count);

    return 0;
}

int my_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {
    long ret;

    asm("pushl %%ebx\n\t" // Line 23
        "movl %%esi,%%ebx\n\t"
        "int $0x80\n\t"
        "popl %%ebx"
        : "=a" (ret)/* output */
        : "0"(SYS_read), "S"((long) fd), "c"((long) buf), "d"((long) count)/* input */
        : "%%ebx"/* clobbered register */
        );
    if (ret >= 0) {
        return (int) ret;
    }
    errno = -ret;
    return -1;
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

Drop one `%` from the clobbered line

```
: "%%ebx"/* clobbered register */
   ^
```

You **must** leave it in in all other lines.

#### EDIT

Remove `extern int errno;` and include `errno.h`.

Comment: Now i am getting :collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]